# Characterization of star-shaped surfaces as diffeomorphisms of the sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Let $f: \mathbb{S}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a positive differantiable function. Define 
$$
S(f) = \{f(p)p \in \mathbb{R}^3 \ | \ p \in \mathbb{S}^2\}.
$$
It can be shown that $S(f)$ is a compact surface diffeomorphic to the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$, with the diffeomorphism given by
$$
\phi(p) = f(p)p, \quad p \in \mathbb{S}^2.
$$

Now, if $S$ is a compact connected surface, we say that $S$ is star-shaped with respect to the origin if $0 \notin S$ and if one cannot draw a straight line from $0$ that is tangent to $S$.

> Our aim is to prove that $S$ is star-shaped with respect to the origin if and only if it is one of the surfaces $S(f)$.

One implication is easy:

Take $S(f)$. Of course $0 \notin S(f)$ because $f > 0$. Now, $S(f)$ is not star-shaped, that is, suppose we could draw a line between $0$ and $f(p)p$ tangent to $S(f)$ at $f(p)p$. Then we would have that $p \in T_{\phi(p)}S(f) = (d\phi)_p(T_p\mathbb{S}^2)$. Then we have that for some $v \in T_p\mathbb{S}^2$
$$
p = (d\phi)_p(v) = (df)_p(v)p + f(p)v.
$$
Taking the scalar product with $v$, we have that $v = 0$, which is a contradiction. Hence $S(f)$ is indeed star-shaped.

My question is: How to prove the converse implication?

Comment: Given $S$, the only $f$ that can work is the one that sends $p \in \Bbb{S}^2$ to $\|v\|$ where $v$ is the intersection of the ray from $0$ to $p$ with $S$. I think you'll need to require $S$ to be smoothly embedded in $\Bbb{R}^3$ (the surface of a the unit cube won't do),

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I believe here "surface" means what is usually called regular surface. Is this enough?

Comment: Yes, regular surface should be good enough. (I was being a bit lax when I wrote "smooth embedding", which is more than you need.)

Comment: And how do we argue that $0$ must be "inside" $S$?

Comment: What you need is that every infinite ray starting at the origin meets $S$ in exactly one point. If some ray $r$ doesn't meet $S$ at all the if you rotate $r$ until it just touches $S$ then that gives a straight line from $0$ to $S$ that is tangent to $S$. If there is a ray $r$ that meets $S$ at two points, then I think you need to choose two adjacent point of intersection and see what happens to those two points as you rotate $r$: if they never meet, $S$ is not connected; if they do meet, you have a ray that is tangent to $S$.

Comment: ... and if $r$ meets $S$ in a line segment, then it is already tangent to $S$.